# How to produce summary stats across multiple columns in R?

Tags: r, data.table

I have a [1,758 x 38] data frame where each row is a job posting while the columns are skills required for each posting (skill1 to skill38). Most job postings have a number of identical skills, except that they are listed in different columns. I would like to produce summary stats for the skills required (e.g, most common skill required). I can produce this for a single column using `data.table`:

```
data[, .N, keyby = skills1]
```

But I am unable to implement a looping mechanism to go through each column. How do I do this?

Comment: It's going to be better if you share a sample of the input and the desired output.

Comment: Try `lapply(data, table)` as this is a small dataset, or `library(reshape2);table(melt(as.matrix(data))[-1])` or `library(data.table);setDT(melt(as.matrix(data))[-1])[, .N, .(Var2, value)]`

Comment: I'm thinking you might be better off with a "long" datafile with 2 columns, e.g.: job / skill, with repeated rows for each job and skill combination.

Comment: What would you want as a result for e.g. `dat <- data.frame(skill1=c("a","a","b"),skill2=c("b","c","c"),skill3=c("c",NA,NA))` ?

Comment: @thelatemail Based on the dimensions, I think the `job` is rownames

Comment: @Hillash Hi, if any answer solves your problem can you click on "accept it" so that other people can see it? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this in `base R` by using `lapply` to loop over the columns.  The output will be a 'list'.

```
lapply(data, table)
```

Or @thelatemail mentioned, the 'wide' format can be converted to 'long' with 2 columns and then do the `table`

```
library(reshape2)
table(melt(as.matrix(data))[-1])
```

A similar method using `data.table` would be

```
library(data.table)
setDT(melt(as.matrix(data))[-1])[, .N, .(Var2, value)]
```

Or using `mtabulate`

```
library(qdapTools)
mtabulate(data)
```

Comment: Yeah, long format seems like the only option. I don't see what `lapply(data,table)` does for you unless the columns `skills1..skills38` have independent meaning (like #1 is most important, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

I use apply inside a wrapper function called sumstats that produces the main statistical indicators:

```
CV = function(x, ...) {sd(x, ...)/mean(x, ...)}
sumstats=function(x, ...) {
  mean.k=function(x) {if (is.numeric(x)) round(mean(x, ...), digits = 2)
                      else "N*N"}
  median.k=function(x) {  if (is.numeric(x)) round(median(x, ...), digits = 2)
                          else "N*N"}
  sd.k=function(x) {  if (is.numeric(x)) round(sd(x, ...), digits = 2)
                      else "N*N"}
  cv.k=function(x) {  if (is.numeric(x)) round(CV(x, ...), digits = 2)
                      else "N*N"}
  min.k=function(x) {  if (is.numeric(x)) round(min(x, ...), digits = 2)
                       else "N*N"}
  max.k=function(x) {  if (is.numeric(x)) round(max(x, ...), digits = 2)
                       else "N*N"}
  sumtable <- cbind(as.matrix(colSums(!is.na(x))), sapply(x,mean.k), sapply(x,median.k), sapply(x,sd.k),  sapply(x,cv.k), sapply(x,min.k), sapply(x,max.k))
  sumtable <- as.data.frame(sumtable);  names(sumtable) <- c("N.obs","Moy","Med","sd","CV", "min","max")
  return(sumtable)
}
```

The [...] allows you to add a na.rm=T argument

```
> head(sumstats(mtcars), 3)
###      N.obs    Moy    Med     sd   CV   min    max
### mpg     32  20.09  19.20   6.03 0.30 10.40  33.90
### cyl     32   6.19   6.00   1.79 0.29  4.00   8.00
### disp    32 230.72 196.30 123.94 0.54 71.10 472.00
```

Note: it doesn't work if you have only one column!